# Python3 merge tuples in a list and remove duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, python-3.6

There might be a similar ask to this one in the past, however wasn't able to find the one that I was looking for,

```
Input = [('Icecream', 'Vanilla'), ('Icecream', 'Chocolate'), ('Icecream', 'Strawberry')]
Output = [('Icecream', ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry'])]
```

Basically, given a list of tuples, need to merge the tuples to form a tuple list without duplicates where the second element in each tuple must be a list.

The Input list might contain more items like below,

```
Input = [('Icecream', 'Vanilla'), ('Icecream', 'Chocolate'), ('Icecream', 'Strawberry'), ('Veggie', 'Carrot'), ('Milk', 'whole'), ('Milk', 'formula')]

Output = [('Icecream', ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry']), ('Veggie', ['Carrot']), ('Milk', ['whole', 'formula'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach on your problem is to convert ***Input*** in to a *dictionary*.

```
Input = [('Icecream', 'Vanilla'), ('Icecream', 'Chocolate'), ('Icecream', 'Strawberry'), ('Veggie', 'Carrot'), ('Milk', 'whole'), ('Milk', 'formula')]

new_dict = {}
for item in Input:
    key, *values = item
    if key not in new_dict:
        new_dict[key] = []
    new_dict[key].append(*values)
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Icecream': ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry'], 'Veggie': ['Carrot'], 'Milk': ['whole', 'formula']}
```

Using this approach, you can easily get the items you need:

```
icecream_flavors = new_dict["Icecream"]
print(icecream_flavors)
```

Output:

```
['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry']
```

But if you really want a *list of tuples* just convert the *dictionary* to a *list*:

```
new_list = list(new_dict.items())
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[('Icecream', ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry']), ('Veggie', ['Carrot']), ('Milk', ['whole', 'formula'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the assumption that the first item in the tuples will always be the same, this will do what you need.

```py
Input = [('Icecream', 'Vanilla'), ('Icecream', 'Chocolate'), ('Icecream', 'Strawberry')]

flavors = []
for i in Input:
    if i[1] not in flavors:
        flavors.append(i[1])

Output = [(Input[0][0], flavors)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is very handy to store these type of data structures. A list in the requested output can then easily be created from it using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

If the ordering is not important, a `set` would be the most logical sub type, leading to the following code.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

Input =  = [
    ('Icecream', 'Vanilla'),
    ('Icecream', 'Chocolate'),
    ('Icecream', 'Strawberry'),
    ('Veggie', 'Carrot'),
    ('Milk', 'whole'),
    ('Milk', 'formula')
]

dd = defaultdict(set)
for key, value in Input:
    dd[key].add(value)
Output = [(key, list(values)) for key, values in dd.items()]
```

If ordering ***is*** important, a dictionary (with arbitrary values, such as `True`) could be used instead, since [dictionaries are insertion ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/10669875) since Python 3.7 (or CPython 3.6):

```py
dd = defaultdict(dict)
for key, value in Input:
    dd[key][value] = True
Output = [(key, list(values)) for key, values in dd.items()]
```

Output of the first is:

```py
[('Icecream', ['Chocolate', 'Strawberry', 'Vanilla']), ('Veggie', ['Carrot']), ('Milk', ['whole', 'formula'])]
```

Output of the latter is identical to the output in the question:

```py
[('Icecream', ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry']), ('Veggie', ['Carrot']), ('Milk', ['whole', 'formula'])]
```

Answer (score -1):

There is 2 different solutions for this. Can elements of a tuple be swapped with each other? Like this

```
Input = [('Vanilla', 'Icecream'), ('Icecream', 'Chocolate'), ('Icecream', 'Strawberry')]
```

If no, the answer is easy. You can use a counter and a while loop (using while loop is important since for loop traverse inside a list's clone as far as I remember in python so that can be a problem) to traverse in the list, for each element, check the other elements. Let's code it.

First of all, Changing the second elements to a list is important. We want an input like this

```
Input = [('Icecream', ['Vanilla']), ('Icecream', ['Chocolate']), ('Icecream', ['Strawberry'])]
```

To do this, this should work

```
for tuple in Input:
    tuple[1] = [tuple[1]]
```

After organizing our input, now we can do what you want

```
counter = 0
while counter<len(Input):
    for tuple in Input[counter+1:]:
        if Input[counter][0] == tuple[0]:
            Input[counter][1].append(tuple[1][0])
            Input.remove(tuple)
counter = counter+1
```

I didn't try it (So there could be mistakes) but I hope you understand what I tried to do. I'm sure you can implement it in your own code with your own style.

By the way, using dictionary data type instead of list of tuples will be much easier. I suggest you to search for dictionaries.